# How can the camera tool in Excel be locked (no scrolling)?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I am currently using the Excel Camera Tool to display a legend on a different sheet. The problem is that the Picture seems to be fixed to a certain part of the page and if I scroll down, the picture moves with the page.

How do I make it so the picture stays in one place unaffected by scrolling?

Comment: What have you researched or tried in order to solve this?

Comment: Some basic googling showed me the answer that @vembutech showed but that did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try "Don’t move or size with cells" option.

Go to Format tab > click on the small down arrow mark next to "Height and Width" box > Properties > choose "Don’t move or size with cells". This should help you.

Comment: This did not work :( As a temporary solution i froze the entire top row and added the legend there